# How to get a property of an IntPtr pointer in C#

Tags: c#, c++, pointers

I'm using some C++ wrappers in my C# project. The thing is that I have a pointer `hd` (of type `IntPtr`) to a C++ type `Head`, which has a property called `xlong`. How can I get that propery? I know two ways:

```
var l = ((Head)Marshal.PtrToStructure(hd, typeof(Head))).xlong;
```

and

```
var l = ((Head*)hd.ToPointer())->xlong;
```

but is there any way of get it directly using Marshal? I've not found anything about it. If not, which way should I use?

`Head` is defined as

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Head
{
    public int w;
    public int h;
    public double wmod;
    public double hmod;
    public IntPtr xlong;
    public IntPtr ylong;
    public int pitch;
    public uint flags;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your actual question, but your property's name won't be `long`. That's a keyword in both C++ and C#. Aside from that, it'll depend (slightly) on the definition of `Head`. In general, your two ways don't necessarily give the same result. It would be helpful if you could show how your C# class `Head` is defined.

Comment: You are right, the property is `xlong`. `Head` is actually an struct. Here is its code: http://pastebin.com/eTQC2u8D

Comment: Thanks, I've taken the liberty of adding that to your question.

Comment: Use [Marshal.ReadIntPtr()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0y7w59b%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  Calculate the offset with Marshal.OffsetOf(), typically in a static constructor.

Comment: @HansPassant Heh, I was writing my answer when you only pointed out `ReadIntPtr` and hadn't mentioned `OffsetOf` yet. It looks a bit silly now.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. @HansPassant I tried your solution and, after seeing hvd answer, I think it suits my needs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it's possible that your two approaches would give different results, but it isn't here: your `Head` struct is [blittable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75dwhxf7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), meaning its representation for unmanaged code and managed code is exactly the same.

Because of that, you can use whichever method suits you best. Your first method:

> ```
> var l = ((Head)Marshal.PtrToStructure(hd, typeof(Head))).xlong;
> ```

has the advantage of not requiring you to write any unsafe code yourself, but letting the system libraries take care of that.

Your second method:

> ```
> var l = ((Head*)hd.ToPointer())->xlong;
> ```

has the advantage of not making an unnecessary copy of your data before extracting the `xlong` field.

Reading the field directly through the `Marshal` class is possible, as Hans Passant points out, by using [`Marshal.ReadIntPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0y7w59b%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). This is not directly suitable: it requires you to first calculate the offset. However, the `Marshal` class already contains a method that does that for you: [`Marshal.OffsetOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y8ewk18b%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

If you take this approach, you may want to cache the result of `Marshal.OffsetOf` in a `static readonly` field, as it will never change, and there is no need to calculate it again for each access.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! I think I'll use the `Marshal.ReadIntPtr` approach, as it doesn't need unsafe code and (I suppose) it doesn't requires to get the structure before getting the property. Thanks again!

Comment: Also and shigtly unrelated, if I wanted to extract the field just one time, should I use the second method?

Comment: @user2223034 If you just want to do this one time, use whichever form is easiest for you to read and fully understand. Which of those that is, is a decision I can't make for you.

Comment: Ok, anyway at the moment it seems that I have to use the fields more than one time. Thanks you. Regards!